# Gradle publishing task somehow depending on output of different task

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I have `build.gradle` file in which I'm trying to do the following:

1. Build War file
2. Publish War file
3. Build docker image based on that War file
4. Push this docker image

Among other tasks I have this `publish` task defined:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        register('customPublishWar', MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'x.x.x'
            artifactId = 'x.x'
            version = project.version
            artifact war
        }
    }
}
```

And the task `setupDocker` that copies the required files from docker directory in my project to the location where the war file is:

```
    dependsOn war
    from 'src/main/docker'
    into war.destinationDirectory
```

When I run these tasks using:

```
./gradlew setupDocker publish
```

I get the following error

```
Task publishPublishWarPublicationToMavenLocalRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task 'publishPublishWarPublicationToMavenLocalRepository' (type 'PublishToMavenRepository').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/IdeaProjects/xx/build/libs/ui.war'.

    Reason: Task 'publishPublishWarPublicationToMavenLocalRepository' uses this output of task 'setupDocker' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task 'setupDocker' as an input of 'publishPublishWarPublicationToMavenLocalRepository'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on 'setupDocker' from 'publishPublishWarPublicationToMavenLocalRepository' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on 'setupDocker' from 'publishPublishWarPublicationToMavenLocalRepository' using Task#mustRunAfter.

    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
```

I've tried hardcoding the path where the files should be copied in my case `into build/libs` didn't help.

I understand that Gradle guarantees the order of the tasks based on the dependendencies. But here, at first sight, it doesn't seem to have dependency on task `setupDocker`.

I've managed to get this working as expected by using afterEvaluate but, I would like to know why the `publishing` fails since I can't see the dependency there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Gradle throws an error is because the input files of the publish task are used as an output location for `setupDocker` but no task dependency is declared between them.

Gradle is trying to help you out because it thinks something is wrong. It's trying to protect you from a situation where a task runs but, because it didn't know about all its predecessors, it does so without first running those predecessors and thus has the wrong inputs.<sup>1</sup>

> But here, at first sight, it doesn't seem to have dependency on task setupDocker.

Yes, exactly: there is no explicit dependency. But because the output directory of `setupDocker` is an input location of the publish task, there is an *implicit* dependency. The publish task uses `setupDocker`'s output.

##### Using `afterEvaluate`

> I've managed to get this working as expected by using afterEvaluate

`afterEvaluate` can help you out in many circumstances but really it's an escape hatch; it's not recommended to use it if possible because it's fragile and becomes difficult to reason about as your project grows (because your build may vary depending on the order in which the `afterEvaluate` blocks run).

##### Declaring an explicit dependency

A somewhat more robust solution would be to declare an explicit dependency, as Gradle suggests. You can do this with code such as:

```
tasks.withType(AbstractPublishToMaven)
    .matching { it.publication.artifactId == "x.x" } // Or any other distinguishing features
    .configureEach { it.dependsOn(setupDocker) }
```

##### A more robust solution: connecting inputs and outputs

Ideally you would connect all the outputs and inputs of the tasks together to avoid these problems. Probably the most straightforward way to do this in your case is to add the Docker setup into your `war` task, ie:

```
tasks.named("war", War) {
    from 'src/main/docker'
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Based on your current setup, because of the other explicit dependencies between tasks, I don't see how a problem could arise. But Gradle doesn't know that, and that also might not remain the case as your project grows.